# Meteor JS - Design Pattern to Avoid Overworking Helpers

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have the following helper, which I think is a bit overworked. What this basically does, is loop through a bunch of SVGs that I have, and if they have corresponding data in the DB, then the fill color of the SVG should change (visual representation of the data).

```
Template.patientContentTreatment.helpers({

    treatments: function () {

        var completedTeeth = $('.svg-tooth-completed > .tooth'); // get all the svgs

        var currentNumber, currentPart;

        for ( var i = 0; i < completedTeeth.length; i++ ) {
            // get a related data-id
            currentNumber = $(completedTeeth[i]).closest('.svg-tooth-completed').data('id');

            // get the related data-title
            currentPart = $(completedTeeth[i]).data('title');

            if ( Treatments.find({ patient_id: Session.get('currentPatient'), tooth_number: currentNumber, tooth_part: currentPart }).fetch().length ) {
                // loop through each SVG and change the fill color if correspoding data is founf
                $(completedTeeth[i]).css({'fill': '#54a6f8', 'fillOpacity': .8});
            }
        }

        return Treatments.find({patient_id: Session.get('currentPatient')});
    }
});
```

I'm still learning how to use Meteor. Before, I had implemented this with autopublish still installed, so it was attached to a `Template.rendered` . But after I moved to using pubs/subs, I found that I couldn't quite implement it the same way as I had before because:

1. There was no way to return a helper from .rendered
2. The subscription data isn't yet ready when the template is rendered anyway. So no data was being displayed.

Here's my previous implementation:

```
    Template.single_patient_treatment_plan.rendered = function () {
        /*
         loop through all teeth
         find if any of them have any findings or treatments attached to them in the database
         if so, change the fill color
        */

    var completedTeeth = $('.svg-tooth-completed > .tooth'),
        currentNumber, currentPart;

    Tracker.autorun(function() {

        for ( var j = 0; j < completedTeeth.length; j++ ) {
            currentNumber = $(completedTeeth[j]).closest('.svg-tooth-completed').data("id");
            currentPart = $(completedTeeth[j]).data("title");

            if (Treatments.find({patient_id: Session.get("current_patient"), tooth_number: currentNumber, tooth_part: currentPart}).fetch().length) {
                $(completedTeeth[j]).css({"fill": "#54A6F8", fillOpacity: .8});
            }
        }
    });
```

So now I've attached the functionality to the helper, but it feels very wrong and bloated. Is there a better way to achieve the same result without using a helper?

Comment: You may want to take a look at FlowRouter to deal with the problem of your subscriptions not being ready. https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#subscription-management. 
You may also try Meteor server methods if you don't need your data to be reactive https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html.

Comment: How are the SVG:s rendered? If it's done in another Meteor template, then most of that logic should go to a template helper there, rather than trying to modify something that's already rendered from elsewhere.

Comment: Could you show your template (html) code? I suspect you could implement a helper at the tooth level which would save a lot of db lookups while avoiding reactive recomputations over the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

I know some of this is in my comment, but as I thought about it a little bit more I decided to give a more comprehensive answer.

If you don't care about having reactive data, then use [Meteor methods](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html).

If you want reactive data I would recommend using [Flow Router](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router) to help deal with the problem of your subscriptions not being ready by checking for it like this:

```
FlowRouter.subsReady("treatments");
```

You may also use ReactiveVars with autorun. [Here's](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/reactive-dict-reactive-vars-and-session-variables/) a good start on reactiveVars. I know this is a lot of reading, but it will definitely help.

So in your rendered you could just do something like:

```
this.treatment = new ReactiveVar({});

this.autorun(function () {
    if(FlowRouter.subsReady("treatments")) {
        // other computations or functions
        this.treatment.set(Treatments.find...);
    }
});
```

This would make your `treatment` variable reactive, allow you to access `treatment` anywhere in the instance of this template, and simplify your helper:

```
treatments: function () {
    return Template.instance().get(); // Reactive computation (see note)
}
```

Note: Helpers are reactive computations. Meaning if you put a reactive variable inside of a helper it becomes an autorun of sorts. [Here's](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactivity-basics-meteors-magic-demystified/) a good resource on this subject.

Also, if you're using an up to date version of Meteor, `rendered` has been deprecated in favor of `onRendered`. [onRendered docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/templates.html#Template-onRendered)